# Short story about a husband-wife duo converting their flabby bodies to exaggerated ideals and then reality ensues

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So, since we've established in Meta that [queries about NSFW stories are alright](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/lets-talk-about-story-id-requests-for-erotica), I have one that's been bouncing around in my head, but which I can't search for right now. A husband and wife duo, obese couch potatoes, answer a want ad for asteroid miners where part of the benefits is a trip to the "Autodoc", which can perform body modifications that are outside of the current legal spec. They pattern themselves after stars in a soap opera they watch and then settle into the conversion process as they start their journey into space. Specifically, the wife gives herself a huge bustline and a wasp waist while her husband goes for Liefeld levels of musculature and then tells the machine to convert the rest of his fat to his manhood.

> They wake up, converted, in zero G and are initially thrilled with their conversion (although he finds that his manhood has to be wrapped around his waist to get around, as it's meters long), but reality ensues. She has trouble moving with all of the excess torso mass having no weight but a lot of inertia. He gets an erection and loses consciousness due to his blood pressure dropping as blood rushes into his new anatomy. Things get worse when they start encountering gravity. He breaks his arm just by waving it, his muscles too much for his bones. She falls forward and can't get back up because her waist can't support her, and she nearly suffocates on her own mammary flesh. I think she just barely makes it to an emergency comm, and they wake up restored to fit, but not exaggerated, bodies, and resolve to live healthy lives but more realistic ones.

There wasn't that much that was erotic in it (they're too handicapped by their bodies to get up to much), but I want to say that I ran into it on a website that marked it as adult. I thought the title was something like "An Apple a Day Keeps the Autodoc Away", but I can't find it by that title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This always seems to happen... my next search, on  TVTropes for "Keeps the Autodoc away", brought up an entry under [Required Secondary Powers](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/RequiredSecondaryPowers/Literature):

> Played straight in the BE Archive story *Keeps The Autodoc Away*, where a couple hack the eponymous AutoDoc to "cure" them of being out of shape. Al tells the machine to, among other things, turn all his fat into a set of enormous, powerful muscles. Near the end, it is revealed, aside from his seven-foot erection knocking him out from blood loss, that his enormous muscles had shattered almost every bone in his body. If it wasn't already obvious, this story isn't exactly safe for work.